# Postgresql, return error with exception

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception

I'm trying to catch exception in a postgresql stored procedure.
Without my "exception when other", my procedure is working. But don't with it.

This is my code :

```
create or replace function test(aaa varchar)
returns table (mmm integer, xxx integer)
as $body$
declare
    ccc             varchar(250);
    ddd     integer;
    xxx     integer;
    mmm         integer;
begin

    select 
        srv_int_id
    into
        mmm
    from
        srv_service
    where
        srv_var_nom = aaa;

    ddd := 1/0;

    xxx := test2(9000,'AAA');

    return query select 
        xxx, 
        mmm;

exception
    when others then
        select ccc = 'Erreur ' || sqlstate || ' dans la procedure test.sql';
        return query select 0,0;

end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

On Squirrel, I hava this error

> Error: ERREUR: la requête n'a pas de destination pour les données résultantes
>     Indice : Si vous voulez annuler les résultats d'un SELECT, utilisez PERFORM > à la place.
>    Où : fonction PL/pgsql p_ech_mes_lire_info_message(character varying), ligne > 44 à instruction SQL
>   SQLState:  42601
>   ErrorCode: 0

But I don't understand it. Do you have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the result of the select in the exception block. The message clearly says that you must use `PERFORM` if you intend to run something ignoring the output (like a `SELECT` whose resultset you are not putting into any variable... unless that `=` means you want to use `INTO ccc`).

Comment: return query is a form of return that allow to return table (set of records)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It help me a lot.